# Convert Rainbow matrix to RBG and save as PNG

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm following this tutorial: https://pyts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_gaf.html in order to generate GADF and GASF matrix.

Everything works well. 
I only need to save, as png, the results contained in `X_gasf[0]` but I don't know how do it.

I already tried this:

```
fig = plt.imshow(X_gadf[0], cmap='rainbow', aspect='equal')
fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig(GADF_path + filename, pad_inches=0, bbox_inches='tight')
```

This code works, but still gives me a white border around the image (it is very important for me not to have any white border).

I also tried this:

```
# Test 1
matplotlib.image.imsave(filename, X_gadf[0])

# Test 2
im = Image.fromarray(X_gadf[0], mode='HSV')
im.save(GADF_path + filename)

# Test 3
cv2.imread(X_gadf[0])
imsave(filename, X_gadf[0])
```

But none of these solutions works. It seems that `X_gadf[0]` is a strange type of image which I cannot manage.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"It seems that X_gadf[0] is a strange type of image"*  It would help if you told us what it is. Show `type(X_gadf[0])`, and if it is a numpy array, show `X_gadf[0].dtype` and `X_gadf[0].shape`.

Comment: `type(X_gadf[0])` return to me: `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`. `X_gadf[0].dtype` return to me `float64`. `X_gadf[0].shape` return to me `(40L, 40L)`

Comment: Thanks.  You also said about your attempts to save the image that "none of these solutions works."  It would be easier for someone to help you if you explain what that means.  Why didn't it work?  What happened?  Did you get an error?  Did you get an image that didn't look the way you expected it to?

Comment: `matplotlib.image.imsave(filename, X_gadf[0])` for example save a png file with all colors wrong. 

`cv2.imread(X_gadf[0])` says `TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, numpy.ndarray found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
matplotlib.image.imsave(filename, X_gasf[0], cmap='rainbow')
```

Looking at the documentation, it seems you have forgot the `cmap='rainbow'`